# Как вывести ключ в словаре столько раз, сколько указано в его значении?

Tags: python, словари

Имею вот такой код, который работает по принципу:

Формат ввода: В первой строке записано натуральное число n (n - количество всех дел). В каждой из следующих n строках записаны пары: строка (цвет задачи), число (номер задачи).

Формат вывода: В n строках выводится упорядоченный список задач: каждая задача в новой строке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def display_hand(hand):
    print ("".join(k*v for (k,v) in d.items()), end = ' ')

d = {}
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    temp_list = list(map(str, input().split()))
    d[temp_list[0]] = temp_list[1]

# Отделил мутню с преобразованием словаря, чтобы значение из str в int перешло
# Пример: ['a': '1', 'b': '2'] --> ['a': 1, 'b': 2]
# ------
d1 = []
d1.append(d)
for sub in d1:
    for key in sub:
        sub[key] = int(sub[key])
# ------
print(d)
display_hand(d)
```

Пример входных и выходных данных прикрепил.
На данный момент на выходе имею:

```
{'lavender': 2, 'fuchsia': 2, 'orchid': 4, 'purple': 1}
```

Имею функцию, которая почти выполняет данный функционал (вообще неправильно работает xd), в общем идея следующая: Считывать число в значении ключа и выводить столько раз, сколько указано в значении. В общем как в примере.
Подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить без словарей:

```
n = int(input())
d = []
for _ in range(n):
    line = input().split()
    d.append((line[0], int(line[1])))

d.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

for el in d:
    print(*el)

# вывести можно еще так:
print(*(' '.join(map(str, el)) for el in d), sep='\n')
```

---

Если вы ***ОЧЕНЬ*** любите однострочники:

```
print(
    *(
        ' '.join(map(str, el))
        for el in sorted(
            [
                (lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1])))(input().split())
                for _ in range(int(input()))
            ],
            key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]),
        )
    ),
    sep='\n'
)
```

**UPD**:
Убрал `key` по [совету Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435874/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/1435880?noredirect=1#comment2561389_1435880):

```
n = int(input())
d = []
for _ in range(n):
    line = input().split()
    d.append((line[0], int(line[1])))

d.sort()

# вывести можно еще так:
print(*(' '.join(map(str, el)) for el in d), sep='\n')
```

```
print(
    *(
        ' '.join(map(str, el))
        for el in sorted(
            [
                (lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1])))(input().split())
                for _ in range(int(input()))
            ],
        )
    ),
    sep='\n'
)
```

Comment: Только по приведенному примеру решения  писать то надо от меньшего к большему. Значит добавляем reverse=True

Comment: @passant `sorted(range(10)) -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` сортировка по умолчанию по возрастанию, т.е. от меньшего к большему

Comment: @passant так вы сами `-x[1]` придумали. в моем коде `x[1]`

Comment: Виноват, погарячился :-)

Comment: Спасибо большое, и в правду можно без словарей, очень помогли. Насчёт однострочников: просто увидел подобное решение на другом сайте, решил украсть строчку, а так тоже не особо люблю)

Comment: В строке `d.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))` `key` не нужен.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy хм, действительно.

Answer (score 1):

если отвечать непосредственно на поставленный вопрос, то ваш словарь можно напечатать примерно так (правда он у вас не отсортирован):

```
d = {'lavender': 2, 'fuchsia': 2, 'orchid': 4, 'purple': 1}

for k,v in d.items():
    for i in range(v):
        print(f'{k} {i+1}')

>>> out
'''
lavender 1
lavender 2
fuchsia 1
fuchsia 2
orchid 1
orchid 2
orchid 3
orchid 4
purple 1
```

**upd**

тут кстати можно обойтись простой сортировкой с ключом, примерно так:

```
n = int(input())
temp_list = []
for i in range(n):
    temp_list.append(input('inp: '))
    

print(*sorted(temp_list, key=lambda x: (x.split()[0], int(x.split()[1]))), sep='\n')

>>> out
'''
4
inp: a 12
inp: b 11
inp: a 5
inp: b 10
a 5
a 12
b 10
b 11
```